# OUYA Custom ROM support

Tags: custom-roms, ouya

[OUYA](http://ouya.tv) has been one of the largest [backed products on Kickstarter](http://www.kickstarter.com/projects/ouya/ouya-a-new-kind-of-video-game-console).

Unfortunately it runs a custom version of Android which does not provide Google Play Store support.  At the same time by design it is supposed to hackable so I wanted to explore the available options in terms of custom ROMs.

Are the any custom ROMs available (or planned/in development) for OUYA?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like the crew over at XDA are already on it:

[XDA OUYA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/forumdisplay.php?f=2103)
Main Page

[Ouya General](http://forum.xda-developers.com/forumdisplay.php?f=2104)
Discussion about the Ouya Android game console (general, tips & tricks, etc)

[Ouya Q&A, Help & Troubleshooting](http://forum.xda-developers.com/forumdisplay.php?f=2105)
For all of your questions relating to the Ouya Android game console

[Ouya Android Development](http://forum.xda-developers.com/forumdisplay.php?f=2106)
Android development for the Ouya game console